# SharePoint 2013 Farm Backup script

Tags: sharepoint-server

Can someone please provide me the SharePoint 2013 Backup PowerShell Script? 
We need to : 
- Take a Weekly back up of the Farm 
- Daily differential backup including site collection 
- Run a scheduled clean-up job to delete the old backup files once in 14 days 
- The script should generate an email and notify the administrators

When we take a full/diff backup of the farm and site collection, does that include the document library as-well?

Can someone please provide me the script the explain the steps on how to take a backup of the documents in the site?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you peform the Full/Differential backup, All the content will be backed up. One thing i am guessing you want to restore the library or files in future, that is not easy with this option.

Let's say you want to restore a Document Library from one of the site collection, In that scenrio...You have to perform full restore in seprate farm and from their you can recover the DL and move it to your production.

Alternate of this is 3rd party tool which will give you granular backup / recovery option.

Now for the Script, You need 3 files and then schedule it.

1. 1st file will perform full backup and schedule to run weekly.[Follow this technet Blog for detailed steps](http://SharePoint%202013%20Backup%20with%20PowerShell%20and%20Task%20Scheduler%20for%20beginners)
2. 2nd file will peform the diff backup and schedule to run daily.[Follow this technet Blog for detailed steps](http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2013/02/23/sharepoint-2013-backup-with-powershell-and-task-scheduler-for-beginners.aspx)
3. 3rd file will clean the old files.[follow the instruction here, they have script file in zip](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mstechsa/archive/2014/02/27/sharepoint-2013-and-2013-powershell-back-up-script.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Waqas.. I followed the instructions in the link mentioned above and scheduled the backup. Works like a charm..

Comment: Great,if it solve the problem then why u unmarked this answer?

Comment: I must have clicked twice and it has unmarked the answer. Sorry and Thanks for your help.

Comment: Np, if u click up arrow then one up vote as well for this effort..